# Why does IGraphBuilder::RenderFile not find ffdshow Video Decoder?

Tags: windows, uac, directshow, codec

When I install K-Lite Codec Pack (5.90 Basic) as an administrator then run an application that calls IGraphBuilder::RenderFile as a standard user, the resulting graph doesn't have the ffdshow video decoder filter. However, when I run the application as the (original installing) admin the ffdshow video decoder is in the graph.

Is there something that I missed when installing the codec?

--bong

Comment: clear preferences somehow? restart?

Answer (score 1):

FFDSHOW maybe is configured not to decode that video format. Open FFDSHOW configuration, find the video format that you have trouble with, in DECODER column, find where it says "DISABLED" and see that you find video format that gives you trouble. If there is "DISABLED" next to it, choose "libavcodec" or "ffmpeg-mt". That way DirectShow will use that codec for that format.

Other, FFDSHOW may have small merit! To fix this, go to DirectShow control (in ffdshow video decoder configuration window) and set Merit to default, or very high, but very high is not recommended... but you can set it only to see if some other codec has higher merit and it gets to be in the graph instead of FFDSHOW.